# statement still running even though while loop is evaluated to false?

Tags: python

```
valid = False
while not valid:
   print("This line runs")
   valid = True
   print("This line also runs...")
```

Midway through the while loop, valid is set to True which means that the while loop condition is now false. My question is why does the last print statement run? At that point isn't the while loop false so shouldn't it break out of the loop?

Comment: NO , after all statements of a loop executed , then loop condition will be checked to see if it is not satisfied then it will not go thought it anymore. if you need end loop there you should use `break`.

Comment: As arman says - the entire while block executes before the instructions pointer will return to the condition (line 2) and be re-evaluated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop condition is checked at the beginning of each loop. If it passes, everything in the body is executed (and the condition is checked again). If you want to exit the middle of the loop body, use the 'break' statement.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a break statement to get your desired outcome, along with an if statement:

```
valid = False
while not valid:
    print("This line runs")
    valid = True
    if valid == True:
        break
    print("This line also runs...")
```

In the code above we have a conditional statement that if it evaluates to True, we will break out of the loop. Before, you had no condition for the loop to check, so the loop iterated through one time before actually catching that valid was no True. In order to break out of your code immediately however you need a break statement like I've shown you above.